# How to Retweet specific user + certain #hastag w/ Tweepy

Tags: twitter, tweepy

I've read through tweepy doc, but couldn't find anything related with retweet a specific user with specific #hashtag?

If tweepy doesn't have this feature, is there any other method to archive this function?

Comment: Problem kind of solved w/ search function " from:@user1 AND #hashtag" now i'm on the next part of figure out how to retweet these search result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use the filter for this. 
I personnaly use the Streming filter. 
Use *on_data()* to handle the status and get the informations you need. 
Then retweet it. 
You should have something like this :

```
class mainStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def on_data(self, status):
        #SOME CODE HERE
        id = status.id_str #Get the status ID
        api.retweet(id) #Retweet the status by providing its ID
    def on_error(self, status_code):
        #SOME CODE HERE
```